# jQuery Mobile - why bind defaults to mobileinit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, styles

I'm using jQuery Mobile and want to turn of Ajax handling because it does some funky stuff with my page. I started with

```
<script src="jquery..."></script>
<script src="jquerymobile..."></script>
Some other stuff...
My own code:
<script src="config.js"></script>
My other javascript files...
```

My idea was that you define the global stuff like libraries at the top, and specifics at the bottom so they are rendered later and "overwrite" the global properties. For example, my own CSS would override jQuery's CSS, and my `config` file would do:

```
$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
```

Which successfully disabled the ajax handling.

However, http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html says to overwrite defaults in a config file **before** jQuery mobile is `src`'d, with some funky notation: (from the page)

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="custom-scripting.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>

//custom-scripting.js
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
  $.extend(  $.mobile , {
    foo: bar
  });
});
```

My question is why do that when you can simply include a one-liner `$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;` in a config file after `jquery-mobile.js`? I assume it's something to do with Javascript's paradigm/style and what not, but I really don't see why you have to go through all that trouble.

So, which one is better to use and why? Why does the documentation recommend this way?

Edit:
And the documentation also says **`mobileinit` is called immediately**, so I should be safe modifying the `$.mobile object` later in a config file right?

Comment: Documentation also has half of your anwser. "Alternatively, you can set them using object property notation." Doesn't explain the "mobileinit" though.

Comment: Yea I noticed that - and as you said it doesn't explain why it's still bound to mobileinit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found why. jQuery mobile initialise himself and defines (= overwrites) the `$.mobile` variable without worrying whether it was already set first.
That's explains the `mobileinit` hook to allow its modification.

Comment: You mean it doesn't necessarily initialize itself once the script is included? That makes sense... Although my code has been working I see the safety in doing it their way - Edit: their page says `mobileinit` is triggered immediately, so if I set my variables in a file later that should be okay. It may not be safe if jQuery changes the way it sets defaults later, but still hmmm

Comment: Hum. It does initialise itself once the script is included, always. It's just it sets up the `$.mobile` variable and doesn't care if it was already defined before.

Comment: But doesn't that mean I can modify it later with just `$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;`? Why go through binding to the mobile init event?

Comment: Later may be too late. jQuery mobile initialise a lot of things (binding events, HTML enhancements).
I'm not sure how it works, but if everything is already processed, changing the configuration after won't work.